# I have a web service .asmx that works with the Visual Studio test page .asmx, but returns a 500 to the client

Tags: javascript, ajax

New at this, I have a web service .asmx that works with the Visual Studio test page .asmx, but returns a 500 to the client.

As soon as I put HTML in the payload from the client the server fails. The Visual Studio test page works with HTML. Thanks for any help.

```
Web Service
.asmx 
[WebMethod, ValidateInput(false)]
        public string HelloWorld(string input)
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

Server web.config
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>

    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" 
controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>

  </system.web>

     ajax
     $.ajax({  
         type: "POST",  
         url: "http://localhost:62093/tMt_webService1In.asmx/HelloWorld",  

         data: "{ 'mail': '" + bodyout + "' }",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

         datatype: "json",
         success: function(responseFromServer) {  
                    alert(responseFromServer.d)  
                },
         error: function(responseFromServer) {  
                    alert("error " + responseFromServer.lastError)  
                }  
       });
```

Comment: are you escaping your HTML in any way in order to return it to the client? What does the response look like when it 'works' locally? 

ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json - is possibly what you want to add to your method. You'll also want to investigate what the 500 error actually says and report back here with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML in your request as the server will reject it if it has characters like `>` or `<` in for security reasons. The feature probably doesn't exist when testing locally (that's why it's ok for you).

So you need a javascript method to strip the bad chars - something like this:

```
function escapeHtml (string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'`=\/]/g, function (s) {
         return entityMap[s];
    });
 }
```

Then when sending the data:

```
 data: "{ 'mail': '" + escapeHtml(bodyout) + "' }",
```

Finally when back server side you can convert it back to html, if memory serves by using using [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_).